# Browserify not watching required files

Tags: coffeescript, gulp, browserify, watchify

I have re-written my gulpfile recently and everything is working very well if not better than before except that on save, my main .coffee file will bundle, but none of the required files trigger a bundle and I can't figure out why. Here are my files:

config file --

```
neat = require('node-neat').includePaths
glob = require 'glob'
dest = "../bld"
src = "./src"

module.exports =

browserSync:
    proxy: "moovweb.dev/"
    ghostMode: 
        clicks: false
        location: false
        forms: false
        scroll: false

sass:
    src: "styl/src/**"
    dest: dest
    settings: 
        sourceComments: 'map',
        imagePath: '/img',
        errLogToConsole: true,
        includePaths: ['sass'].concat(neat)

markup:
    src: ['../*.php', '../inc/*.php', '../templates/*.php']

images:
    src: "/img/**"
    dest: dest + "/img"

browserify:
    bundleConfigs: [
        #entries: glob.sync('./js/src/**/*.coffee') 
        entries: './js/src/app.coffee'
        dest: dest
        extensions: ['.coffee']
        outputName: 'app.js'
        debug: true
    ]
```

browserify file --

```
browserify   = require 'browserify'
browserSync  = require 'browser-sync'
watchify     = require 'watchify'
bundleLogger = require '../util/bundleLogger'
gulp         = require 'gulp'
handleErrors = require '../util/handleErrors'
source       = require 'vinyl-source-stream'
config       = require('../config').browserify
_            = require 'lodash'

browserifyTask = (callback, devMode) ->

bundleQueue = config.bundleConfigs.length

browserifyThis = (bundleConfig) ->

    if devMode
        _.extend bundleConfig, watchify.args, debug: true
        bundleConfig = _.omit bundleConfig, ['external', 'require']

    b = browserify(bundleConfig)

    bundle = ->
        bundleLogger.start(bundleConfig.outputName)

        return b
            .bundle()
            .on 'error', handleErrors
            .pipe(source(bundleConfig.outputName))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(bundleConfig.dest))
            .on 'end', reportFinished
            .pipe(browserSync.reload
                stream: true
            )

    b = watchify(b)
    b.on 'update', bundle
    bundleLogger.watch(bundleConfig.outputName)

    reportFinished = ->
        bundleLogger.end(bundleConfig.outputName)

        if bundleQueue
            bundleQueue--
            if bundleQueue is 0
                callback()
                return

    return bundle()

config.bundleConfigs.forEach(browserifyThis)

gulp.task 'browserify', browserifyTask

module.exports = browserifyTask
```

When I save app.coffee, everything bundles fine. But when I save any of the .coffee files requires in app.coffee, it does not bundle unless I re-save app.coffee. I have several custom libraries that are required in a directory structure like this:

```
/js
- app.coffee
- /lib
--lib-1.coffee
--lib-2.coffee
--etc.coffee
```

I have tried globbing, but that just produces and error, and most everything else is set up as it was before I re-wrote it. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that `devMode` is set to something truthy? If it isn't, you won't get the `watchify.args` added to your `bundleConfig`.

Comment: @ben Yes, I am. I was sure to check that.

Comment: re-create the problem in a simpler setup and iteratively add parts until you hit your problem.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having a similar problem :/

Comment: @BradJenn Actually, no. Due to time constraints for a project, I ended up just adding the browserify task to my gulp.watch() task and running the compilation from there. While not being ideal, this works fine for the busy interim. I can post what I have for that if you would like?

Comment: @thesublimeobject no thats okay, i figured out what i was doing wrong in the end. Something stupid in the end. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation. Files in certain folders or sometimes individual files would be compiled, but would not trigger watches when changed or saved.

It turns out the problem was caused by the fact that, by default, OS X's filesystem is case-insensitive, so while Browserify was able to get the files it needed, I think the utility functions Watchify uses either got confused or never started in the first place for those files, or maybe the Browserify cache got loaded with the original and then never found the updated files in the non-existent paths.

Fixing the case of paths in my require() statements fixed the issue. Also, there is a plugin for checking this programmatically: https://github.com/zertosh/dep-case-verify